# Annual mean, standard deviation for markedly nonuniformly sampled metric

Tags: time-series, sampling, mean, standard-deviation, seasonality

I expect that this is a common issue and that I just need the correct terminology so that I can Google more efficiently. I'm interested in calculating an annual mean and standard deviation for a quantity $y$ that is sampled throughout a year. Due to logistical issues, there are far more samples in the summer than in the winter leading to a very patchy data set. If I simply take an average of all my samples within a year, for example, the mean will be biased by the heterogeneous sampling intensity. Is there a standard approach for dealing with this issue?

Comment: I think you're right to be worried about seasonality. Saying more about the phenomena of interest would give context: I am guessing at an ecological and/or environmental topic. So, why do you think an annual mean and SD is either needed or useful here? why don't you fit a model with year and time of year as predictors and use that to model variation?

Comment: @NickCox Thanks for the reply. It is indeed ecological/environmental. I'm actually referring to numerous variables some of which exhibit more seasonality than others. For example, sea-surface temperature, chlorophyll-a concentration, salinity, zooplankton biomass, etc. The reason I'm interested in the metrics is to provide a simple way of comparing years (e.g., this was a warm year or that was a highly productive year) as well as seasonal variability (e.g., environmental conditions were fairly constant or fluctuated a lot this year). Would model fitting be the most common solution to this?

Comment: It's something I have addressed often; I can't vouch for what is "most common" in e.g. oceanography or marine ecology. There are several threads here. There is a `seasonality` tag. Also search for "trigonometric predictors".